# HTTPS Form Submission with cURL(or anything better)

Tags: php, curl, https

```
function login_board($url,$ch)
{

    $cookie="cookie.txt";
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user_id=myid&password=mypass&action
    =login');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    echo $content = curl_exec( $ch );

}
```

The following approach doesn't log me into the site. If I run this twice consecutively, it just shows me the login page again instead of showing me the welcome screen.

If I try to access a page inside, it gives me a bad request.

Answer (score 1):

cookie jar will only save the cookie, however on the next requests u need to send back the cookie as well .. look into CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE